# Sort array to get the nearest from today first

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, sorting

I have an array like this :

```
array = [
  {
    "title": "a",
    "date": "2021-10-25T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-20T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-28T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-30T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-26T18:00:00.000"
  }
]
```

And I want to sort it with the nearest object from today first.
I try with sort but I think, I don't have the good method to do this.

This is what I tried :

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
   return (new Date(b.battle_start) > new Date()) - (new Date(a.battle_start) < new Date())
})
```

And this is what I want

```
array = [
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-26T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "a",
    "date": "2021-10-25T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-28T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-30T18:00:00.000"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "date": "2021-10-20T18:00:00.000"
  }
]
```

Comment: If you don't show an attempt, it's likely your question will be downvoted, unanswered or closed. Always show that you've tried something. 'Sort' is what you want though

Comment: Thanks, I understand, I edit my post with my attempt :)

Comment: You describe what you want to get first. What do you want to get second and third, ... can you provide the expected output for your example input?

Comment: Sorry, I edit with the result

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be adapted to use `Math.abs`, so that distance to past or future will be regarded in the same way:

```js
const array = [{"title": "a","date": "2021-10-25T18:00:00.000"},{"title": "b","date": "2021-10-20T18:00:00.000"},{"title": "b","date": "2021-10-28T18:00:00.000"},{"title": "b","date": "2021-10-30T18:00:00.000"},{"title": "b","date": "2021-10-26T18:00:00.000"}];
let now = Date.now();
array.sort((a,b) =>
   Math.abs(Date.parse(a.date) - now) - Math.abs(Date.parse(b.date) - now)
);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that via :

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return (Math.abs(new Date(a.battle_start) - new Date())) - Math.abs((new Date(b.battle_start) - new Date()))
})
```

What you want to compare is the distance between "now" and the target date.

Comment: Perfect ! It's absolutly what I need ! Thanks a lot